# How to call subroutines in Fortran parallelized with MPI in an SMPD environment

Tags: mpi, daemon, subroutine

My problem is that when I try to call a simple subroutine when I use mpi in Fortran, the simple multi-purpose Daemon (SMPD) gives this kind of error :

```
    `CreateProcess failed, error 2
    unable to start the local smpd manager.
    CreateProcess failed, error 2
    CreateProcess failed, error 2
    unable to start the local smpd manager.
    CreateProcess failed, error 2
    unable to start the local smpd manager.
    unable to start the local smpd manager.
    invalid command received, unable to determine the destination: 'cmd=result src=0
    dest=1 tag=9 cmd_tag=9 ctx_key=0 result=SUCCESS '
    invalid command received, unable to determine the destination: 'cmd=result src=0
    dest=1 tag=10 cmd_tag=9 ctx_key=2 result=SUCCESS '
    invalid command received, unable to determine the destination: 'cmd=result src=0
    dest=1 tag=11 cmd_tag=9 ctx_key=1 result=SUCCESS '
    invalid command received, unable to determine the destination: 'cmd=result src=0
    dest=1 tag=12 cmd_tag=9 ctx_key=3 result=SUCCESS '
    mpiexec aborting job...`
```

When I comment the call line, the code works perfectly and the SMPD doesn't display any error.

I asked the compiler to generate a reentrant code but the SMPD still give the same error.
Could you please give me a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Do you have any code, that you could show us to illustrate the problem? As it is posed right now, I, at least, don't even understand the question. Do you use MPI process spawning features?